# Forking two branches on GitHub

Tags: github, version, branch, repo

I contribute to the [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial) repo and have forked it [here](https://github.com/sindizzy/DotSpatial).
The repo has gone from v2 to v3 (both based on .NET Framework) and [v4](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/blob/master/Changelog.md) based on .NET Core. My plan is to continue the v3 line for my work projects (and those who wish to use my fork). But additionally I want to contribute to the v4 line.

Since the v3 is now discontinued I will probably not make any pull requests on that branch. On the other hand, I will be making PRs to the current v4.

GitHub allows you to fork the main repo only once, so how can I fork two separate branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forking is a Github specific method which is only useful if you want to keep the realtionship to, or make PRs against the parent repository.

There's nothing stopping you cloning a repository and then committing that to Github - you just have to manually reconcile changes/make PRs since Github doesn't see it as a fork.

I would fork the repo in Github and use that for v4, since you are likely to want to use the Forking functionality in making PRs etc.

I would then clone the repo again (locally) under a different name, e.g. `DotSpatialv3` and then create/push that to Github as a separate repo.

Comment: OK I think I see what you are saying. Let me give that a shot and I will report back.

Comment: I think that is going to work. I updated my fork to sync with the current master which is v4. I then found the V3 and downloaded it and will upload to a totally separate repo under my account so that it can continue.